# How can I express this query in sqlalchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Here is my SQL query:

```
select survey_spec.survey_spec_id, cr.login as created_by, installed_at, req.login as requested_by, role
from survey_spec
        join (select survey_spec_id, role, max(installed_at) as installed_at from survey_installation_history group by 1, 2) latest using (survey_spec_id)
        left join survey_installation_history using (survey_spec_id, role, installed_at)
        left join users cr on created_by = cr.user_id
        left join users req on requested_by = req.user_id
where survey_id = :survey_id
order by created_at desc, installed_at desc
```

I have ORM entities for `survey_spec`, `survey_installation_history`, and `users`, and `survey_spec.installations` is a relationship to `survey_installation_history` using `survey_spec_id` as the key.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the example output of what you have got so far?  i.e. the output of:

```
print survey_spec.query.filter(survey_spec.survey_id==survey_id).options(
         eagerload(...))
```

If you just want to load up your entities, you could bypass the SQL generation and load from your given [literal SQL](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html?highlight=from_statement#using-literal-sql), something along the lines of:

```
session.query(survey_spec).from_statement("""select survey_spec.survey_spec_id, cr.login as created_by, installed_at, req.login as requested_by, role
from survey_spec
 join (select survey_spec_id, role, max(installed_at) as installed_at from survey_installation_history group by 1, 2) latest using (survey_spec_id)
 left join survey_installation_history using (survey_spec_id, role, installed_at)
 left join users cr on created_by = cr.user_id
 left join users req on requested_by = req.user_id
where survey_id = :survey_id
order by created_at desc, installed_at desc""").params(survey_id=survey_id).all()
```